# Encryption Key with Puttygen - AUtomation Extracts

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio, encryption, ftp

my end goal is to be able to utilize Tracking Extracts. To do this, I'm needing to move a file from the Safehouse to my FTP folder, decrypt it, and then export/move into a DE etc.

My problem is the encryption of the extracted data. When the data is moved from the safehouse to my FTP folder, it's automatically encrypted, whether I select a key or not.

When I added a public customer key, however when I attempted to add a Private Key via PuTTY Key, I can't save the private key in the format required for Salesforce Marketing Cloud.

Has anyone else run into this issue? Is there a way I can move the file from the Safehouse to the FTP without encryption?

Comment: Are you sure it is encrypted, and not just zipped? If you generate a tracking extract and name the exported file something.csv, opening it will fail, as Tracking Extracts will always be one zip file with multiple CSVs, each corresponding to e.g. opens or clicks.

Comment: I agree with @LukasLunow ... Please watch these great videos by [Cameron Robert](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/40604/cameron-robert) these videos might help you to better understand... 1) [create an Automated Tracking Extract](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BioqZXr5luI&t=0s) 2) [Import Tracking Extract to DE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3xeu7m_7bKw)

Comment: Thanks for the comments @LukasLunow and Vishal. I have watched Cameron's videos.  That's why I'm confused. I've successfully transferred the file to my folder, but I never selected encryption. After I ran into that problem, I went through the process of setting up encryption, which led me to my above situation. I've recorded a video here of the problem - https://loom.com/share/52ca996339cb40f9bb1e60f231413739 .

Comment: As your video shows, your tracking extract activity is generating a file **without .zip suffix** (this is also confirmed when looking at your FTP folder), while your last activity where you are attempting to unzip the file, is looking for a filename **with .zip suffix.** This has nothing to do with encryption, just an error from your side.

Comment: Right. I was showing that I can't unzip a file because a zipped file with that naming convention doesn't exist, showing that it's encrypted, not zipped. Problem is, I never encrypted it. Does it automatically get encrypted when moved from the Safehouse?

Comment: Okay I get what you mean now. Think I'm going to find a nice hole to crawl into. You were right @LukasLunow. I forgot to add the '.zip' suffice on my tracking extract. Appreciate you and Vishal's patience. Sometimes the devil is in the details. If you want to copy and paste your comment as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Also adding this link with time stamp, should anyone in the future run across this problem.  - https://youtu.be/BioqZXr5luI?t=79

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is zipped and not encrypted. If you generate a tracking extract and name the exported file *something.csv*, opening it will fail, as Tracking Extracts will always be one zip file with multiple CSVs, each corresponding to e.g. opens or clicks. So it is best practice to name your tracking extract files *something.zip* instead.

You should also validate, whether or not your tracking extract activity is generating a file with a *.zip* suffix. This naming convention should correspond across all your your activities: Extract, File Transfer, etc.

[Here is a good video](https://youtu.be/BioqZXr5luI) by [Cameron Robert](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/40604/cameron-robert) presenting how to configure a Tracking Extract.